# Using Selenium Android WebDriver from within APK

Tags: android, selenium

I have been reading up about Selenium Android WebDriver and from all the examples, it looks to me as though I need my phone connected to my PC or run an AVD to send the test data...

I was looking for an API that I could include into my app for the following purpose:
When I receive an order from my website, my app will notify me, show the order details and then have a "Place Order" button which then opens the web browser, navigates to my suppliers website and places an order similarly to how I use Selenium with C# on my PC.

My supplier also has an android app where I can place orders that way. Am I missing something with Selenium or is it not capable of doing the tasks I need? If not then I guess I could unpack my suppliers APK and search for the web requests and what data is sent, or somehow track the data being sent/received when I place an order with their app and simply replicate it with my own.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Android WebDriver is a wrapped browser, you can install WebDriver APK and connect to same Wi-Fi lan that is your computer and send test code through phone ip.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("yourPhoneIp/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.android());
driver.navigate().to("someUrl");
```

If you want tool that can use entire phone GUI and apps you can try:

1. [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/)
2. [Android MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)

Comment: I don't want to send test code to my phone at all... I want my phone to generate it's own code. So say I am out having a meal with the family, I notice I have an order, and I place it... My phone then does all the button presses and input for me (removes user input error) and I just sit back and watch. So I am going to guess that Selenium is not for me. I looked at Robotium, but that looked as though it had to be connected to a PC too?

Comment: You want to have a bot that is doing some job all day in your phone through apps and alert you for specific condition? then you need to write some code in Robotium or MonkerRunner. Good Luck.

Comment: Sort of, the app will query my database every 10-15 minutes for new orders. If my web server sends back a new order (or more) then my app will create a notification to alert me. I then press the notification and it opens my app, shows me details of the order(s) and for each one I press "Place Order" which then opens the browser app, navigates to my suppliers website, places the order, closes the browser and returns to my app which will then notify my server that the order has been placed.

Comment: You need to write your own APK(app) for that. Try to search some service in google.

Comment: Writing my own app was what I had in mind, my question was if it is possible to control Selenium/Robotium from within my own app?

Comment: You can control with robotium your own app.